# How to update multiple rows in sql from array data using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to update multiple records in my database using laravel eloquent but is getting errors when trying to update using an array.

I am not really sure how to correctly get the data from the array to my update function.

The array I am passing looks like this.

[image]

My Database table looks like

id | checklistid | categoryid | isCheck | created_at | updated_at

My Controller looks like this.

```
public function updateCategoryListData(Request $request){
    $checklistdata = $request->get('checklist');
    $id = $request->get('checklistid');
    $dataset = [] ;
    foreach($checklistdata as $key =>$value){
                $dataset[] = ['checklistid'=>$id,'categoryid' => $key,'isCheck'=>$value];
           }
        categorylistcontent::where([['checklistid',$id], ['categoryid', $dataset=>['categoryid'] ]])
            ->update($dataset['isCheck']);
}
```

Would you be able to advise how I can use the array to get the 'checklistid' and 'categoryid' to be used as the where clause of the update statement and then the 'isCheck' to be set in the update.

Comment: `The array I am passing looks like this` which array you are refering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `dataset` array, rather do the following:

```
foreach($checklistdata as $key =>$value){
    categorylistcontent::where('checklistid',$id)->where('categoryid',$key)
        ->update(['isCheck'=>$value]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I never knew laravel can read the array automatically when you do the update. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with just one query, but you could do that with two queries. An example:

```
$check = categorylistcontent::query();
$notCheck = categorylistcontent::query();

foreach ($request->checklist as $item) {
    $query = $item['isCheck'] === 1 ? 'check' : 'notCheck';
    $$query->orWhere(function($q) use($item) {
        $q->where('checklistid', $item['checklistid'])->where('categoryid', $item['categoryid']);
    }
}

$check->update(['check' => 1]);
$notCheck->update(['check' => 1]);
```

I haven't tested this exact code, but I think it will be helpful for you to get the idea.

Comment: Will try this approach, Thank you!

Comment: How to update like this?

`ids:
array (size=3)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 2

values:
array (size=3)
  0 => float 0
  1 => float 0
  2 => float 0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update multiple rows by putting it in foreach loop

eg:

```
foreach($checklistdata as $key =>$value){
$dataset[] = ['checklistid'=>$id,'categoryid' => $key,'isCheck'=>$value];

categorylistcontent::where([['checklistid',$id], ['categoryid', $dataset=>['categoryid'] ]])
            ->update($dataset['isCheck']);
}
```